# Create and relate arrays depending on their position in angular5

Tags: arrays, ionic3, angular5

I have the following strings which I will convert into two seperate arrays:

```
Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido:Equipamiento Perdido:Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente:Pedido con documentación pendiente:Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia
```

Every time the symbol "**:**" appears it means its a new value inside the array and if theres "**,**" its a group of values.

Im not sure if by using just **.split()** it would seperate the values in the array correctly.

Afterwards I have a similar string with codes which I would do the same procedure as above:

```
EQSOLREENVIO:EQPER:EQCAN:EQRECHKODOC:EQAUS,EQCDE,EQDDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC:EQINDEV:EQCAMBIODI,EQENV,EQFECHA,EQFIESTA,EQINCITRASP:EQENT:EQDEV:EQRCH:EQADMIPDV:EQCRE,EQRETENER:EQRECOOFI
```

I than need to relate these two arrays where the **position 0** of the **first** array has the codes of **position 0** of the **second** array.

Im not sure how to approach this second part on relating the arrays by their positions.

**EDIT**:

Heres an example of the relationship:

**Position 0:** Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido --> EQSOLREENVIO

**Position 1:** Equipamiento Perdido --> EQPER

**Position 2:** Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente --> EQCAN

**Position 3:** Pedido con documentación pendiente --> EQRECHKODOC

**Position 4:** Pedido en incidencia --> EQAUS,EQCDE,EQDDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC

So the array should look somewhat like this:

```
Array { 0: Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido
             { 0: EQSOLREENVIO }
        1: Equipamiento Perdido
             { 0: EQPER }
        2: Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente
             { 0: EQCAN }
        3: Pedido con documentación pendiente
             { 0: EQRECHKODOC }
        4: Pedido en incidencia
             { 0: EQAUS
               1: EQCDE
               2: EQDDE... }
```

Comment: There's one problem: what you show in your example result code - that's not an Array in JS. Arrays have a syntax of `[item1, item2, item3, [item4, item5]]`. Objects have the syntax of `{item1: item2, item3: [item4, item5]}`. Please pay attention to the curly and square braces, the commas, colons - and everything. You can reference an item in an Array by its index, and an item in an Object by its key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet does what I understood from your question.

1. Parses the **Strings** to an **Array** by **,** then **:**
2. Associates the second **Array**'s 0th element with the first **Array's** 0th element
3. Returns an **Object** (as an associative **Array**)

```js
const first = 'Cliente solicita reenvío de pedido:Equipamiento Perdido:Pedido cancelado a petición de cliente:Pedido con documentación pendiente:Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia,Pedido en incidencia'

const second = 'EQSOLREENVIO:EQPER:EQCAN:EQRECHKODOC:EQAUS,EQCDE,EQDDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC:EQINDEV:EQCAMBIODI,EQENV,EQFECHA,EQFIESTA,EQINCITRASP:EQENT:EQDEV:EQRCH:EQADMIPDV:EQCRE,EQRETENER:EQRECOOFI'

const separate = (s) => {
  return s.split(':').map(e => e.split(','))
}

const relate = (s1, s2) => {
  const sep1 = separate(s1)
  const sep2 = separate(s2)
  const obj1 = {}
  sep1.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (e.length) e = e[0]
    if (!obj1[e]) obj1[e] = []
    obj1[e] = sep2[i]
  })
  return obj1
}

console.log(relate(first, second)) // as an object containing arrays
console.log(Object.entries(relate(first, second))) // as array
```

## SNIPPET EDITED ACCORDING TO ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

Comment: Hi muka, thats almost entirely correct but the last code "EQAUS" if you see in my question there are other codes after this one seperated by a comma which are related to that same group "Pedido en incidencia"

Comment: So, you need to pair up all the strings and codes, not only the 0th element?

Comment: Exactly, every : is a different group and every , is a different value in that group

Comment: Modified the snippet (`relate2()`) - I think it does what you need.

Comment: I have added an example to my question of how it should turn out, I have tried your new code and its not doing it correctly

Comment: Then maybe this last version is closer to what you want. I added two types of return value - one is an Object, the other is an Array.